# How to prevent accident swipe in iOS game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios12

During testing of our SpriteKit iOS game on iPad (currently running iOS 12 beta), we found that dragging on screen might accidentally trigger system swipe up gesture (and go to Home or Multitasking screen).

Is there a way to disable the system swipe (or maybe need to swipe twice) so to prevent accidental swipe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can defer the gestures with

```
//Tell the system you prefer deferring
override func preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures() -> UIRectEdge {

    return [.bottom] //Whatever side you want to defer, see UIRectEdge() https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirectedge
}
```

Then call `setNeedsUpdateOfScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures()` when you want the `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` to fire.

With this you can now absorb the gesture first and decide whether or not you want to pass it on.

References:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887507-setneedsupdateofscreenedgesdefer
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uirectedge

Tutorial:
https://useyourloaf.com/blog/avoiding-conflicts-with-system-gestures-at-screen-edges/

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 11**

Changed to an instance property...

```
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    return .bottom
}
```

or, return .all to defer all edges.